# BufferedImage.getRGB with grayscale BMP

Tags: image, bufferedimage, bmp

The images above correspond to the same black-to-white linear gradient, with the pixel in the middle having a 50% gray value (~127).

The code

```
 BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(filename);
 int p = im.getRGB(im.getWidth()/2, im.getHeight()/2);
 System.out.printf("%x\n",p);
```

outputs the expected value (`ff7f7f7f`) for BMP-rgb and GIF, but for the first (BMP grayscale) I get `ffbbbbbb`. It seems as if a (strong) gamma correction were applied, only in that case. Why?

[image: bmp 8 bits] BMP grayscale (8 bpp) [original](http://hjg.com.ar/varios/2012/gray.bmp)

[image: bmp 24 bts] BMP rgb  (24 bpp) [original](http://hjg.com.ar/varios/2012/grayrgb.bmp)

[image: gif] GIF (8 bpp) [original](http://hjg.com.ar/varios/2012/gray.gif)

Comment: It seems I've hit this issue http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6467250